# Literate agda programming in org-mode

Tags: org-babel, literate-programming

How could I write literate (and exportable to latex) **Agda** code in org-mode?

- Org-babel would be a great option, but there is no `ob-agda2` (I think?). I have tried defining an `org-babel-execute` function for agda following [the template](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html#develop) `ob-template.el`, but my knowledge of Elisp is not enough to fill all the required functions.
- [Literate Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.LiterateAgda) works well with Latex files, but it needs the extension of the file to be `.lagda` and only detects Agda code between `\begin{code} ... \end{code}`, instead of the org-mode syntax of `#+begin_src agda2`.

A possible solution right now would be to add some Latex export options to make `\begin{code}` export correctly to Latex

```
#+latex_header: \usepackage{verbatim}
#+latex_header: \newenvironment{code}{\verbatim}{\endverbatim}
```

and to keep changing betweeen major modes (org and agda) to edit the same file, with an `.org.lagda` extension.  Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: The solution on the "Using beamer..." section of this [page](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.LiterateAgda) works. The pdf compilation gets a bit complex, but the final result is perfect. I still would like to ask if there is a simpler way using org-babel or keeping only one file.